# c# Use system user in application

Tags: c#

I created an application in C # for file copying . Some users do not have access to records in writing but only for reading.

Is it possible in my application to use the "system" user to be able to copy my files in these folders ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your application could just bypass that restriction, why would it exist in the first place?

Comment: How about getting access to write files? What you ask for is simply called as Hacking.

Comment: How I can bypass that restriction ?

Comment: This is impersonation in C#.
Check this out [link](http://bit.ly/144aHov)